# Error code No file or Directory found when trying to install Audacity

Tags: linux, file, directory, helper, audacity

~$ flatpak install flathub org.audacityteam.Audacity
Looking for matches…
Required runtime for org.audacityteam.Audacity/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.38) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [Y/n]: y

org.audacityteam.Audacity permissions:
ipc    pulseaudio    x11    devices    file access [1]

```
[1] host


    ID                                          Arch              Branch           Remote            Download
```

1. [✗] org.gnome.Platform                          x86_64            3.38             flathub              75.1 MB / 343.3 MB
2. [ ] org.gnome.Platform.Locale                   x86_64            3.38             flathub           < 326.0 MB (partial)
3. [ ] org.audacityteam.Audacity                   x86_64            stable           flathub            < 31.2 MB
4. [ ] org.audacityteam.Audacity.Codecs            x86_64            stable           flathub             < 8.7 MB
5. [ ] org.audacityteam.Audacity.Locale            x86_64            stable           flathub             < 5.1 MB (partial)

Error: opendir(refs/remotes): No such file or directory
error: Failed to install org.gnome.Platform: opendir(refs/remotes): No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to go into the `/.var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs` (start at system root) directory. Then create the required folders. My system needed a `remotes` and a `heads` folder. You can leave them empty, unless `flatpak` tries to open non-exisistent folders in there. You will also have to do the same in the `~/.local/share/flatpak/repo/refs` directory if you want to do user-only installations that do not require the admin password.